# Elasticsearch mappings ignored

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello look like mappings don't work for me, so i had tried to delete index and re-index but always getting same results. Here is how mappings look and response from GET search endpoint. So entry_id field is mapped as integer, but returned as a string.

localhost:9200/entries-vlatest/_mapping

```
{
    "entries-v1631182320": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "properties": {
                    "entry_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response from get Search localhost:9200/entries-vlatest/_search

```
  "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 2,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "entries-v1631182320",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "15",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "entry_id": "15",
               
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So i have tried to delete index and re-index with

POST localhost:9200/_reindex

```
    {
      "source": {
        "index": "entries-v1631182320"
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "new_index"
      }
    }
Result:
    {
        "took": 257,
        "timed_out": false,
        "total": 1,
        "updated": 0,
        "created": 1,
        "deleted": 0,
        "batches": 1,
        "version_conflicts": 0,
        "noops": 0,
        "retries": {
            "bulk": 0,
            "search": 0
        },
        "throttled_millis": 0,
        "requests_per_second": -1.0,
        "throttled_until_millis": 0,
        "failures": []
    }
```

But again getting same results, when i search re-indexed
GET localhost:9200/new_index/_search

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "novi",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "15",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "entry_id": "15"
                   
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working correctly. You're sending your source document with `entry_id` as a string and Elasticsearch will not modify that source document, but store it as is.

However, the `entry_id` field will be indexed and stored as described in your mapping, i.e. as an `integer`

If you want to "see" an integer, then add the value as an integer in your source document. But in the end it doesn't make any difference, that value will be seen and handled as specified in your mapping, i.e. as an integer, even though you sent it as a string in your document.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand why it's not returned as an integer even if i did re-indexing?

Comment: It has nothing to do with reindexing, it has to do with what you send in your source document. Elasticsearch will never modify anything in your source documents. So if you send a field value as a string, that value will stay as a string in the _source even though it's mapped to integer or any other type. Reindexing simply recopies your source document from one index to another, so if the value is a string in the source index, it will still be a string in the target index

Comment: Ok makes sense but then what is the purpose of mapping?

Comment: As I said, you need to distinguish between the _source document, which is the raw data you send to ES, and what is indexed from that _source document, which is what gets indexed into the inverted index and other data structures. What you send is `"15"` (i.e. a stringified integer), but what ES ultimately indexes is `15` (i.e. the integer 15) since this is what you have instructed your mapping to do. So as far as queries are concerned, `entry_id` will behave as an integer (i.e. what your mapping specifies) and not as a string

Comment: OK so sorting will be numeric, that is important to me.

Comment: Thx, please vote up if you find this question usefull

Comment: Yes, sorting, aggregations (sum, etc) will be based on an integer value not a string one. You should have mentioned this in your question I would have told you right away that it would have worked ;-)

Comment: Sir tnx again, have a nice day